# How can i get xpath count in selenium webdriver using jasmine javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
var sample1 = browser.findElements(driver.By.xpath('//somenode')).getXpathCount();
console.log( sample1.intValue() );
```

while printing the count I am getting error:

> error occuredTypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findElements method returns an Array promise, so you have to do something like this:

```
browser.findElements(driver.By.xpath('//somenode')).then(function(elements) {
  var count = elements.length;
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @alecxe stated, the syntax for getXpathCount() is browser.getXpathCount("//somenode").

I saw you opened an issue on the selenium git and had more code there. What isn't showing here is you have just the following.

```
var browser = require('selenium-webdriver');
var sample1 = browser.findElements(driver.By.xpath('//somenode')).getXpathCount();
console.log( sample1.intValue() );
```

I haven't used WebDriverJs, so someone please correct me if I am wrong, but I think you need to create a browser object. Right now you only have created a driver object named browser.

Can you try the following snippet?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();

browser.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki');
browser.getXpathCount('//*[@id="www-wikipedia-org"]/div[1]/div');
```

Comment: yeah i tried this  I am still getting the same error.Anyway by using elements.length as stated below answer i am able to find the count

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using `getXpathCount()` correctly. You should do it this way:

```
browser.getXpathCount("//somenode");
```

Comment: yeah i tried with this, but still getting "error occuredTypeError: undefined is not a function"